# pass value to view to javascript

Tags: javascript, symfony

I have a dialog to show information in symfony2. This dialog have 2 buttons, when I click in a botton I want to call a function with parameter that show in the view... How to pass this parameter?

This is the view in the dialog

```
<p>Empresa: {{ company }}</p>
    <p>Idea: {{ idea.getName() }}</p>
    {% for pago in pagos %}
    <p>
        <b> Nombre:</b> {{pago['name']}} </br>
        <b> Puntos:</b> {{pago['win']}} i+ </br>
    </p>
    {% endfor %}
```

I want to pass company

this is my javascript

```
$("a[rel='buy']").click(function(){
    $("#buy").load($(this).attr('href')).dialog({
        height: 310,
        width: 660,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Buy": function(){
                $(this).load("{{path('AddingPurcharse')}}"
                );
            },
            cancel : function(){
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

I want to pass de value of company, to pass it to  function `AddingPurcharse`

```
$(this).load("{{path('AddingPurcharse', 'company' : company)}}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the attribute data-* for stock your information in items, like company name. Else, you can parse HTML with jQuery selectors.

More information about data-* : [html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

For read the attribute data-*, you can use the function `attr()` in query :

```
var company = $("p").attr("data-company");
```

Comment: You may want to use `$('p').data('company')` better.

Comment: Thanks  @moonwave99 I do it and work fine, but I want to pass a array to. I have problem with this data... I do this  var datoId = document.getElementById('datos');
var datos= new Array();
datos= datoId.getAttribute('data-pagos');, but when a see de debug the value of datos is only "array"... any idea.

Comment: I don't understand very well your problem . You want push an array in data-pagos field ? Or do you explain that getAttribute not return a good value ?